# excel - count blanks per row filtered on name

Tags: excel, count

Greeetings

I am trying to create a formula in excel for counting blank cells (that is the easy part ;))

But I would like to find the number of blank cells per Name in RowA.

```
Sheet1
    A   B
    1   *Name*  *Data*
    2   Brian   data1
    3   Niels   data1
    4   Kurt    data2
    5   Kurt    
    6   Brian   data3
    7   Brian   
    8   Niels   data2
```

Should result in:

Sheet2

```
    A   B
1   Name    Percent Empty Cells
2   Brian   50%
3   Niels   0%
4   Kurt    50%
```

since 50 percent of Brians fields are empty.
since 50 percent of Kurts fields are empty.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the empty cells, assuming that F2 is the name value you want to look up:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,F2,B:B,"")
```

To get the percentage of empty cells:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,F2,B:B,"")/COUNTIF(A:A,F2)
```